How to feed a RAG / vector database with mysql data (incl. relations)
I've been searching high and low and I'm close enough to give up.
I'm playing around with LLMs and vector databases / RAGs (looking at Milvus ATM.
I found plenty of articles on how to integrate RAGs with Mysql, however they always include only one table at a time.
I'm interested in connecting/syncing/leverage the power of vector databases with mysql data, that however include relations amongst structured data (e.g. I have two tables with classes and students, and a third table providing which students attended which class - the value/information really is in the relations.
Now, either I'm approaching this from a completely wrong standpoint or my searching skills have dramatically faded.
Anyone who cares to explain and/or suggest any readings on the topic? Or a hint on how to achieve the above?
Thanks, cheers from Milan, Italy.

If the relatiinship is important, then you should not use a vector database, but a graph database.

Alternative is that you leave everything in mysql and use LLM to create sql statements to  and display those results in your answer.

Thanks @Shadow, I'll look into graph databases. When you say, alternatively, to use SQL statements into the LLM, are you talking about some langchain kind of set-up?

Use LLM to generate the sql queries. For example, if the user asks, who attends English class on Mondays, LLM can generate the sql query that returns the answer and the LLM can generate a few sentences around it.

Understood, thanks. Just one last clarification - "LLM can generate the sql query that returns the answer" means that there's some connector where the LLM will also run the query, to then generate the sentences, right? Apologies if this is obvious, I never built this set-up before :)

Standard python mysql connector
